# Como Dividir as Cores?

Tags: html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de introduzir as cores da bandeira da frança no retângulo acima,mas não sei dividir as cores(nem sei se tem como sou noob no assunto rs)alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sua pergunta não esta clara, coloque o que vc já tem de código, e indique melhor onde eh que vc quer colocar as cores

Comment: olha essa imagem que fiz no paint e veja se me entende agora > https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/2019-03-30_-2-png

Comment: se quiser posso te passar o link do jogo para voce testar e ver como funciona,é apenas 70mb

Comment: Cara tem 1000 formas de fazer isso, vc precisa dar mais detalhes, comece Editando a sua pergunta e incluindo o que vc já tem de código

Comment: > https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/2019-03-30_-3-png < codigos que tenho e sei usar (são os unicos que sei, foram esses que usei pra fazer o texto que esta na imagem "TSUBASA 10")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.grid-container>div {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="grid-container">
            <div style="background: blue;"></div>
            <div style="background: white;"></div>
            <div style="background: red;"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```